# Filtering on a page where line items are displayed as tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement. In my page currently user details are displayed as a table and it has a filtering option, if the user type a character the table will be filtered with their name filtered with the character typed. Now this has to be redesigned to display the customers using tiles, like each customer details are displayed in rectangle with their details in it. So far so good.
my question is, can I implement a filtering function on this tiles page, same way fileting has been done in the table. is there any solutions currently available ?.

any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pretty much the same way. It's just a different way with presenting the information. You could possible have those filtered tiles pop up at top, or make the ones not in the query disappear. I cant really offer code with this, but I'm sure that you practically already have it. Could you possible link an example or the actual site?